# Test class can only have one constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Anybody encountered this error

initializationError(junit.framework.TestSuite): Test class can only have one constructor

Use Case.

I have 2 TestScripts in a TestSuite. If I dynamically create the TestSuite and then add the 2 testScripts and invoke this

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);
```

where clazz is the TestSuite class.

However I if invoke the JUnitCore.runClasses on each 2 TestScripts there is no problem.

I used JUnit3.

I have similar question with this [JUnit error - IllegalArgumentException:Test class can only have one constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415325/junit-error-illegalargumentexceptiontest-class-can-only-have-one-constructor), but mine involves creating the test suite class dynamically. Reason being is that there is a usecase that I could just include 1 testscript in a testsuite or i could have 2 testscripts in a testsuite.

**UPDATE code:**

```
public class ScriptTest1 extends TestCase { 
    private ScriptTest1() { }   
    public void testMethod1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}

public class ScriptTest2 extends TestCase { 
    private ScriptTest2() { }   
    public void testMethod2() {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

Then in another class

```
File file = new File("file to ScriptTest.class");
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

//construct a new test suite
TestSuite ts = new TestSuite("Sample Test Suite with only ScriptTest1");
ts.addTestSuite((Class<? extends TestCase>) clazz);

Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ts.getClass());
HashSet<String> failureMethod = new HashSet<String>();
for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
     System.out.println("Failure: " + failure.toString());      
}
```

Failure will output: initializationError(junit.framework.TestSuite): Test class can only have one constructor
However if I just directly do this, it will run fine.

```
File file = new File("file to ScriptTest.class");
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(clazz);
```

I created the test classes in JUnit4 and Im running my main program with dependency on JUnit4 also.

Comment: Are you sure that the classes that implement the tests (you call them "testscripts") each have not more than one constructor?

Comment: Yeah im sure. its a simple junit3 test. 

    public class ScriptTest extends TestCase {
    }

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? Including the ScriptTest constructor? And the code for the Suite as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the class junit.framework.TestSuite.class to JUnitCore.runClasses(). JUnitCore.runClasses tries to instantiate the class. To avoid problems, it requires that any class that you pass has only one constructor [*]. TestSuite has multiple public constructors.

Try:

```
TestResult result = new TestResult();
ts.run(result);

for (Enumeration<TestFailure> failures = result.failures(); failures.hasMoreElements();) {
    TestFailure testFailure = failures.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Failure: " + testFailure.toString());      
}
```

In the meantime, think about upgradng your test cases from JUnit 3 to JUnit 4, JUnit 3 is getting quite old now.

[*] Except for Parameterized tests, etc. In the OP's use case, it's true.

Comment: Yeah I know. But that is the only way I can build a TestSuite. I don't really have any idea how to programmatically create a TestSuite in JUnit4.

Comment: Thanks for this however it introduced another error. "has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()", which this site talks in detail http://cleveralias.blogs.com/thought_spearmints/2005/11/index.

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, if you are injecting dependency, `private final Whatever whatever;`

Erase the `final` and erase the constructor.

That's works for me

Comment: The OP code snippet doesn't seem to show dependancy injection.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to launch a *parent* test class instead of *descendants*. See also https://coderanch.com/t/721675/engineering/JUnit-error-IllegalArgumentException-Test-class. In order not to mix next time I changed it to `abstract class`.